# How to send email by custom form

Tags: module, magento2.3, email

I created custom form module, if customer submit the form i need to get all values by email.

**My module files are**

> Customform\ReturnRequest\Block\Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Customform\ReturnRequest\Block;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

  public function getFormAction() 
 { 
  return '/returnrequest/index/index';   
 }
}
```

> Customform\ReturnRequest\Controller\Index\Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Customform\ReturnRequest\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
 protected $_pageFactory;

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
 {
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
 }

 public function execute()
 {      
    $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (!empty($post)) {
        // Retrieve your form data

        // Display the succes form validation message
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Sucessfully you had done your returns order !');

        // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl('/returnrequest/index/index');

        return $resultRedirect;
     }


    return $this->_pageFactory->create();
   }
 }
```

> Customform\ReturnRequest\etc\frontend\routes.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
   <router id="standard">
    <route frontName="returnrequest" id="returnrequest">
        <module name="Customform_ReturnRequest"/>
    </route>
  </router>
 </config>
```

> Customform\ReturnRequest\view\frontend\layout\returnrequest_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Customform\ReturnRequest\Block\Index" name="helloworld_index_index" template="Customform_ReturnRequest::index.phtml" />
 </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

> Customform\ReturnRequest\view\frontend\templates\index.phtml

```
   <form id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction()?>">

      <input name="name" id="name" class="input-text" type="text" />
      <input name="email" id="email" class="input-text" type="email" />          

      <button type="submit" id="add" title="" class="action submit primary">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Request Return')) ?></span>
        </button>

    </form>
```

My form displaying good. i need to set only email function. 
Please let me know . Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create **email_templates.xml**

> Customform\ReturnRequest\etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="hello_template" label="Hello World" file="hello.html" type="html" module="Webkul_Hello" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Now create email template file **hello.html** in folder

> Customform/ReturnRequest/view/frontend/email

```
<!--@subject Email Subject @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"skin url=\"images/logo_email.gif\" _area='frontend'":"Email Logo Image"}
@-->
<!--@styles
body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
@-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1 style="font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;line-height:22px;margin:0 0 11px 0;">{{trans "Hello"}},</h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                            {{var message}}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA;text-align:center;">
                            <center>
                                <p style="font-size:12px;margin:0;">
                                    <strong>{{trans "Thank you"}}</strong>
                                </p>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Now Update your controller with my code:

> Customform\ReturnRequest\Controller\Index\Index.php

```
    <?php

namespace Customform\ReturnRequest\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
 protected $storeManager;
 protected $_transportBuilder;
 protected $inlineTranslation;
 protected $_pageFactory;

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
 {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
 }

 public function execute()
 {      
    $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (!empty($post)) {
        // Retrieve your form data

        // Display the succes form validation message
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Sucessfully you had done your returns order !');

        $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $templateVars = array(
            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
            'customer_name' => 'John Doe',
            'message'    => 'Hello World!!.'
            );
        $from = array('email' => "test@website.com", 'name' => 'Name of Sender');
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $to = array('john@website.com');
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('hello_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($to)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl('/returnrequest/index/index');

        return $resultRedirect;
     }


    return $this->_pageFactory->create();
   }
 }
```

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: hello file is an html or else phtml?

Comment: It is HTML it contains your email template content

Comment: Thank you, let me try

Comment: I didn't get email

Comment: Did you update TO and FROM address?

Comment: Yeah i changed to my address

Comment: Please check normal script for email sending. If that will work then this should work.

Comment: Thank you, it receive after 5 mins

Comment: Thank you :) not it's working fine

Comment: Please MARK AS READ, If this is helping you.

Comment: Yeah i had 
Done